# Exchange ETH for WETH via smart contract function call

Tags: solidity

I'm attempting to write a simple solidity contract that can:

- receive ETH
- convert ETH to WETH
- display ETH balance
- display WETH balance

ETH operations appear to work as expected however whenever I try to call any of the WETH functions I receive an error and the transaction is reverted.

Is there something wrong with the way I am trying to instantiate or interact with the WETH token?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external view returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external view returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
}

interface IWETH is IERC20 {
    function deposit() external payable;
    function withdraw(uint) external;
}

contract Scrath {

    address private weth = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

    function sendEth() external payable {}

    function ethBalance() public view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        _balance =  address(this).balance;
        return _balance;
    }

    function convertToWeth() external payable {
        uint256 eth = ethBalance();
        IWETH(weth).deposit{value: eth}();
    }

    function wethBalance() external view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        _balance = IWETH(weth).balanceOf(address(this));
        return _balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to inject into Web3 through Remix IDE?

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you testing this smart contract? If you are using any other environment than eth mainnet for testing, (ie. remix local js chains, local ganache, ethereum testnets) the WETH contract will not be deployed at the same hardcoded address.

Tools like hardhat, truffle ect. usually have a functionality to fork an existing chain, ie in your case eth mainnet and perform tests on it.

If you dont want to do that and test in something like remix or hardhat, make sure you deploy a WETH contract to that local chain first, then modify your hardcoded address to match it.

Alternatively you could make the WETH address variable an immutable variable that is set inside the contract's constructor. Then you can set it once at deployment to match the address of WETH on whatever chain you are deploying on.

```
contract Scrath {

    address private immutable weth;

    constructor(address _weth){
       weth = _weth;
    }

    function sendEth() external payable {}

    function ethBalance() public view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        _balance =  address(this).balance;
        return _balance;
    }

    function convertToWeth() external payable {
        uint256 eth = ethBalance();
        IWETH(weth).deposit{value: eth}();
    }

    function wethBalance() external view returns(uint256 _balance) {
        _balance = IWETH(weth).balanceOf(address(this));
        return _balance;
    }

}
```